# numeric inaccuracy collision resolution

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution

I need an idea, please :). I've implemented moving AABB -> AABB collision detection (3D), returning the time of impact.

When I calculate `time_of_impact * velocity` I sometimes have accuracy problems, e.g. player should stay at `y=64`, but after multiplication it's `y=63.999996`. So the next iteration returns `time_of_impact < 0.0`, but its resolution, doesn't solve the collision, because again it stays at `y=63.999996`. Moving the player forward then collides with the floor tile from the side (x or z axis).

How can an algorithm handle numeric inaccuracy?
I use 32bit and didn't test 64bit precision, but at some point, it should also happen.

Thanks so far.

Comment: I've linked this Q&A to a [previous thread we have about improving numeric stability in AABB collision detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/163306/39518). If this fix does not apply to your code, edit your question to show your code and we can re-open it for answers specific to your approach.